# Silverlight clientaccesspolicy.xml crossdomain.xml

Tags: silverlight, web-services, firebug

I am one of 2 developers on a silverlight project that is hosted online. The problem is that  i seem to randomly have problems with our webservices not working (This never happens to my colleague).

Using firebug, i had a look at any problems that it was reporting and i found this:

GET clientaccesspolicy.xml 404 not found
GET crossdomain.xml 404 not found

Any ideas why only i have a problem with like this?

We have both cleared out our cache and recycled the application pool of the webserver... no joy.

Thanks,
Kohan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem came when accessing the site without typing "www."
I should have known to check that first. :(

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the client attempts to connect to a domain on which it is not hosted. The policy files are used to grant access to that server from the SL client.

Are you both running the client from the same location? Double check your proxy settings and hosts file too.

Comment: Yes, we are both sat next to each other on the same network, using the same internet to connect to the same client online.

The client is not hosted by us, it is hosted by a provider.

Answer (score 1):

So the webserver intermittently returns 404 errors on the policy file?  What version IIS?

If your colleague *never* gets the error, compare the request headers between his system and yours to be sure there isn't something weird going on.

If the policy file is hosted by a provider and you're getting intermittent 404 errors you should put in a ticket with the provider.

Comment: Okay thanks, i will check this out Monday, not back in the office till then.

Comment: Just had a look at the headers and they seem to be exactly the same, nothing showing up that would make sense of this problem. It is worth noting that this is only a problem in FireFox at the moment so i am going to put this problem to bed. If it starts effecting me working in other browsers i'll look into it more.

Thanks for the suggestions all the same.